# QGis-Modeler: Using "Basic statistic" values for "Extract by expression" - Outliers

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-modeler, extract, soil

I'm working on Qgis 3.34.0. with Model Designer. I'm working with soil data (Organic matter for example).
I have 2 data sources, "cal OM" and "lab OM".

The data I'll use will be "cal OM". From this layer, I want to extract values based on an expression. I've already used the tool "basic statistics for fields".

How can I set the right formula?

[image]

I want to take out outliers (1st quartile-1.5*IQR and 3rd quartile+1.5*IQR) only if the maximum value from the "Cal OM"exceeds in a 10% the maximum value from "lab OM". [image]

This is the formula I've made: "OM"< (  @Statistics_Ecom_cal_OM_THIRDQUARTILE +1.5* @Statistics_Ecom_cal_OM_IQR ) and "OM">( @Statistics_Ecom_cal_OM_FIRSTQUARTILE -1.5* @Statistics_Ecom_cal_OM_IQR )

Everything is on shapefile-reprojected.
Eventually I want to make a more complex model, which includes interpolation.

Solved a part: I used as dependencies "Statistics ecom cal OM"for "extract by expression" and calculated the outliers apart:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking, how to set the output of one part of a model as the input of another part?

Comment: More like how to do the exact formula, I've been struggling with that

Comment: *The formula or if I can change something from the model.
Thanks